# New to Objective-c, Hello World

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I am just starting to learn Objective-C programming. I'm developing in Xcode 4.2 on Mac OS X version 10.7.2 on an iMac. I am reading the book "Programming in Objective-C" by Stephen Kochan, which contains a simple "Hello World" example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog (@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

It bombs out with lots of errors when compiling:

> /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:313:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]

There are lots more like this. Is there something that needs to be done before compiling for the first time? Some setup in Xcode?

Comment: For those of us who don't have that book, you might want to describe the steps you took in that example. Did you create a new command-line project? Is this file called main.m? Did you remember to deselect Automatic Reference Counting?

Answer (score 6):

`Unknown typename NSString` means you are passing objective c code to (normal) c compiler

Comment: I did create this as a command line project... and it is called main.m

Comment: Found the problem... when creating the project I left the "type" as just "c". I changed it to "Foundation" and it worked. This pulled in all of the proper header files for Objective-C, before it was just trying to compile to plain old c.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks like you choose the wrong application project to start with. Seems like you choose something that got to do with c program

I suggest you click File -> new project and choose Cocoa Application to start with.

Then You copy your code and put it inside 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method in your appdelegate file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog (@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return YES;

}
```

Build and run the program. You should be able to see your Hello World in your console log..

Comment: No, you can write a command-line tool in Objective-C. The Cocoa Application template is used to create an application with a GUI.

Comment: Yes u can.. And its not a command line tool.. You can definitely see the result in the console log

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. hchattaway is trying to write a command-line program; your suggestion to use the Cocoa Application template would have him write a GUI program instead.

Comment: How can you tell that he tried to write a command line program? He just tried to make his first hello world program in objective c and i think the above code might just do that. Correct me if I'm wrong :p

Comment: Because it looks like code for a command-line program; namely, it links to Foundation, not Cocoa, is written entirely in a `main` function, outputs to the console, and never calls `NSApplicationMain`.

Comment: thats an assumption. My assumption is he's trying to create his first hello world objective c which can be done in several ways.. Plus the code that he writes other than main function does not resemble a command line program.

Comment: In what way does it not resemble a command-line program? (He's not even importing anything from Cocoa, so it most likely not a GUI program.)

Comment: in the template the current version XCode gives me, that NSAutoReleasePool initting and releasing is in the main.m, so I think this example is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I found that after I chose "Command line", I selected "Core foundation" rather than "Foundation" in the window where I wrote the project name. This was what caused the error for me. Be careful!