# Import Unity along with UIKit project

Tags: objective-c, uikit, unity-game-engine

We are working on a game which is based on MapKit from Apple. Choosing to attack some venues from the map trigger some built-in minigames which currently are made in cocos2d. We want to change one of this minigames and replace it with a Unity-based game, so I wonder if it's possible to run code generated by Unity along with the rest of the project.

I don't want some deep integration between Unity and the rest of the project, just to start the Unity-based game and to stop it when the player finished the minigame. Do you know if this is possible and what are the steps to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Found this: http://alexanderwong.me/post/29949258838/building-a-ios-unity-uiview-uiviewcontroller but when I add files to my project I get a lot of errors such "Unknown type name NSString" and "Expected unqualified-id"

Comment: Sound like a plain C-project like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074579/new-to-objective-c-hello-world

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824754/strange-compiler-error-during-sharekit-integration/10765702#10765702 helped me to get rid of the errors.

Comment: So you've got it up and running? It's a pretty interesting point which could introduce new use cases for Unity

Comment: Not yet, but now I can compile it along with my code. In the next days I will try to make Unity work along with cocos2d and UIKit.